# Unity Gameobject not visible in Hololens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am trying to build a HoloLens 2 app using unity.

I added an 3D object from blender, it works fine with the Remote Holographic app, I can interact with it and move around using the Hololens 2 device. But I am unable to get it in the app, the app build then it shows nothing just an empty scene.

The steps I do to build the app are:

1. add the MRTK v2 foundation package
2. file >> build settings >> switch to Universal Windows Platform.
3. Player setting >> Player >> XR settings >> Virtual Reality support
4. switch the Target device to Hololens and Architecture to ARM64
5. add the Open Scenes to build settings.
6. Mixed Realty Toolkit >> Utilities >> Build Window >> build Appx

I have Unity 2019.4.19f1 and MRTK 2.5.4

Comment: is the object black by any chance?

Comment: No it's white-gray, I can see it when using the Remote holographic app through unity.  I also have another problem sometimes the built app cant  be loaded in hololense it stuck at the first scree and not showing built by unity logo.

Comment: Well the thing is, if it is being rendered black it would be transparent for you ;) I think what @nka_Zz was going for is an issue with the Universal Render Pipeline

Comment: Did you make sure, that your scene taht you added to the build settings is the first in the list (0) ? Unity always starts the application with that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to the leacy XR plugin, not the new one.
also the architecture should be ARM not ARM64

Answer (score 1):

To rule out the possibility that it is due to Unity's configuration, check your settings with the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-base-02) (if you haven't already done so).

What I notice is that x64 is selected for the architecture in the tutorial. I don't think that's the reason, but it's worth a test.

If everything else is identical, check whether it works with the simple cube (analogous to the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-base-04) here).

Cheers